# Creating a Linux driver for a time stamping IP

Tags: embedded, linux-device-driver

I have an embedded board with Linux running on it. I want to use PTP (IEEE 1588) to synchronize the board to a network grand master. The board uses a Xilinx Zynq device that has ARM processors and an FPGA. I have developed some IP to do the time stamping and RTC. I now need to interface these two IPs with Linux. So I need to create some drivers, but as I am not a Linux expert I dont really know how to do it.

I have a basic understanding of driver development but the issue is how to interface the time stamping. I plan to use the Linux PTP program to do the PTP.  From what I can work out from looking at other drivers that do this, there is a SO_TIMESTAMPING flag that enables hardware time stamping. Then there are some functions in the skb (socket buffer) files that set it up. Could someone explain what would be required in a driver to interface to the PTP program.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Writing kernel modules is not an easy task. You will definitely face a learning curve.

There are more pieces than this, but at a high level, there are a few things that you will need to do.

1. Determine where in memory you want to exchange information between your IP and driver.
2. Add a device tree entry that specifies the memory range you will use.
3. Write a driver to interface with your IP.
4. Expose the information to userspace.

While you are figuring things out, you can hard-code the memory addresses in your driver, but eventually the driver should pull the memory regions from the device tree. 
Some tips:

- The driver will need to request the memory region(s)(request_mem_region) and then map it (ioremap_nocache).
- You can then expose that information to userspace by making files in /proc/ or
  /dev/, by creating sockets, or various other method
- If you are going to use UDP sockets in the kernel, check out https://lwn.net/Articles/625077/
- Start with some introduction to module writing tutorials such as http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-1-introduction/